# MySQL ZRM restore failed with mysql error unknown command \0

Tags: mysql, database-restore, amanda

I am restoring an incremental backup with ZRM server on mysql database. I am having blob data in the tables. The incremental backup not getting restored and giving mysql error `unknown command '\0'`.

Tried changing the `max_allowed_packet_size` to 1 GB and also getting the issue. Checked the ZRM configuration for adding --hex-blob but did of no use.

Error after restoring the backup with --verbose:

```
restore:INFO: ZRM for MySQL Community Edition - version 2.2.0
restore:INFO: Reading options from file /etc/mysql-zrm/mysql-zrm.conf
BackupSet1:restore:WARNING: Could not open file /etc/mysql-zrm/BackupSet1/last_backup. No such file or directory
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: Using /usr/share/mysql-zrm/plugins/ssh-copy.pl as the default plugin since copy-plugin has not been specified
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: ZRM Temporary configuration file = /etc/mysql-zrm/BackupSet1/tmpewWlH.conf
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: {
BackupSet1:restore:INFO:        backup-level=0
BackupSet1:restore:INFO:        destination=/mysql_backup/mysql-zrm
BackupSet1:restore:INFO:        databases=main
BackupSet1:restore:INFO:        source-directory=/mysql_backup/mysql-zrm/DailyBackup_SSH/20130212170902
BackupSet1:restore:INFO:        mail-policy=always
BackupSet1:restore:INFO:        backup-mode=raw
BackupSet1:restore:INFO:        password=******
BackupSet1:restore:INFO:        backup-type=regular
BackupSet1:restore:INFO:        copy-plugin=/usr/share/mysql-zrm/plugins/ssh-copy.pl
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: }
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: Getting mysql variables
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: mysqladmin --password="*****"  variables
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: datadir is /var/lib/mysql/
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: mysql_version is 5.5.20-log
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: InnoDB data file are /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: InnoDB log dir is /var/lib/mysql/.
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: Command used is 'cat "/mysql_backup/mysql-zrm/DailyBackup_SSH/20130212170902/backup-data"  | "/usr/share/mysql-zrm/plugins/encrypt.pl" -d |  "/usr/bin/gzip" -d  | tar  --same-owner -xpsC  "/mysql_backup/mysql-zrm/DailyBackup_SSH/20130212170902"  2>/tmp/gIJmM6bLwF'
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: Executing pre-restore-plugin
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: BINLOG =  mysqlbinlog --password="*****" --database=main "/mysql_backup/mysql-zrm/DailyBackup_SSH/20130212170902"/mysql-bin.[0-9]* >> /tmp/nADdF9OfBn
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: Restoring incremental to file
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: mysqlbinlog --password="*****"  --database=main "/mysql_backup/mysql-zrm/DailyBackup_SSH/20130212170902"/mysql-bin.[0-9]* >> /tmp/nADdF9OfBn
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: restoring using command mysql --password="*****" -e "source /tmp/nADdF9OfBn;"
BackupSet1:restore:ERROR: Output of command: 'mysql --password="*****" -e "source /tmp/nADdF9OfBn;"' is {
ERROR at line 202087 in file: '/tmp/nADdF9OfBn': `Unknown command '\0'`.
}
ERROR: Incremental restore failed
BackupSet1:restore:ERROR: Incremental restore failed
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: Removing all of the uncompressed/unencrypted data
BackupSet1:restore:INFO: Executing post-restore-plugin
BackupSet1:restore:ERROR: Restore failed
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `--verbose` to see what's going on.

Comment: I have edited the question with --verbose option for restoring database. Sorry for the late edit @Quanta

Comment: Which mysql verion are you running on the client side?

Comment: Mysql version is 5.5.20. Currently we have changed to logical backup where we have got the option `--extra-mysqldump-options="--hex-blob --skip-extended-insert"` and configured in the `mysq-zrm.conf` file. Testing this option which may help us for future errors, but still did not get any solution for restoring the backups taken before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did not get any solution to restore the taken blob data backup causing `Unknown command` error. For avoiding this restore error we have added `extra-mysqldump-options="--hex-blob --skip-extended-insert"` in `mysql-zrm.conf` file.

Hope this helps somebody!!